# Como puedo modificar el texto de una línea en concreto de un fichero.txt?

Tags: python

Tengo un fichero.txt
En la línea 8 hay escrito un número, y necesito cambiar el valor de esa línea. Quiero que cuando lo ejecute Python, en esa línea aparezca un 1, después un 2, luego un 3 y así